# Warhammer 40K backstory

Tags: warhammer-40k

Is there any backstory to the different races in Warhammer 40K...?

Comment: Why not ask on the [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A basic introduction is available via [Games Workshop](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/content/article.jsp?pageMode=multi&categoryId=cat440130a&pIndex=4&aId=9300005&start=5), and a general overview can be found on the [Warhammer_40,000 page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_40,000).

Beyond that, there is an enormous amount of information available in the Codexes.  Games workshop produces a Codex for each race which contains a lot of backstory as well as units and rules specific to that race.

Comment: There's also a huge amount of backstory in issues of White Dwarf magazine, and the Black Library range of novels.

Answer (score 3):

You can also hit up the [Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Main_Page) for relatively detailed historical entries;  just bear in mind that being a wiki, there is some information on there that is of disputed quality.

Answer (score 3):

On the official part, GW has also the [Astronomican](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/content/astronomican.jsp) with some articles

On the unnoficial, apart from the already mentioned Lexicanum, [warhammer40k.wikia.com](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) has also a lot of background (generic, not as unit-level deep as Lexicanum).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_40,000_species

Comment: Could you please expand on this at all? A single link shouldn't really suffice as an answer